# How to prove that the corresponding matrix is unitary

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, diagonalization

Let's say we are given hermitian matrix $H$.
How to prove that the matrix $M$, formed from eigenvectors of $H$ is unitary? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. The identity matrix $I_n$ is Hermitian. Any basis is a basis of eigenvectors for $I_n$. This yields any $M$ invertible. But not every invertible matrix is unitary. Worse, just take one eigenvector, $x$. Then the set of eigenvectors $\{x,\ldots,x\}$ yields a rank $1$, hence non invertible for $n\geq 2$, matrix $M$.

What is true is that if $H$ is Hermitian, there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. In which case, indeed, the corresponding matrix $M$ is unitary. In other words, there exists $M$ unitary such that $MHM^*$ is (real) diagonal.

Comment: The columns of M are normalized so that <mi|mi>=1 , where mi is a ith column of matrix M

Comment: @ABCD   This is not what you have written in your question. As it is written, your statement is false.

Comment: I am sorry for that)

Comment: @ABCD No problem! But If you are taking an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, that's different. Then yes, $M$ is unitary. As you can see in the answer above.